# Pipe tar command to SSH

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, tar

I want to create the tar file on another server. When I execute this command it works, but when I put this command in my shell script it returns an error.

```
tar cvzf - prod_test.txt| ssh oracle@192.168.1.248 "cat > prod_test5.tar.gz"
```

> tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: prod_test.txt|:
>   Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: ssh: Cannot stat: No such
>   file or directory tar: oracle@192.168.1.248: Cannot stat: No such file
>   or directory tar: "cat: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: >:
>   Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: prod_test4.tar.gz": Cannot
>   stat: No such file or directory vÂ ÷Om7 7Þ'(tar:

```
#!/bin/sh
dy=`date +%a`
bk='/d01/backup'
```

## Transfer Command

```
trans_oracle='tar cvzf -  prod_test.txt| ssh oracle@192.168.1.248 "cat >  prod_test4.tar.gz"'
```

## Delete Command

```
del_oracle='rm -f '$bk'/'$dy'_apps_indus_prod.tar.gz'
echo '****** Start Time ******' >> bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
date >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'

--#Transfer Backup
$trans_oracle
--#Delete Backup
#$del_oracle

echo '******  End Time  ******' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
date >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'

printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_backuplog.log'
printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_backuplog.log'
```

error

> tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: prod_test.txt|:
>   Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: ssh: Cannot stat: No such
>   file or directory tar: oracle@192.168.1.248: Cannot stat: No such file
>   or directory tar: "cat: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: >:
>   Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: prod_test4.tar.gz": Cannot
>   stat: No such file or directory vÂ ÷Om7 7Þ'(tar: Error exit delayed
>   from previous errors –

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh
dy=`date +%a`
bk='/d01/backup'

#Transfer Command 
trans_oracle='tar cvzf -  prod_test.txt| ssh oracle@192.168.1.248 "cat >  prod_test4.tar.gz"'
#Delete Command
del_oracle='rm -f '$bk'/'$dy'_apps_indus_prod.tar.gz'


echo '****** Start Time ******' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
date >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'

#Transfer Backup
$trans_oracle
#Delete Backup
#$del_oracle

echo '******  End Time  ******' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
date >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'

printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_backuplog.log'
printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_backuplog.log'
```

Comment: Welcome to unix.se! Please post the error message. When you do not want to locally create a file with tar, you can drop the `f` option and `-`: `tar cvz prod_test.txt| ssh oracle@192.168.1.248 "cat > prod_test5.tar.gz"`. Both versions worked for me.

Comment: tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: prod_test.txt|: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: ssh: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: oracle@192.168.1.248: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: "cat: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: >: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: prod_test4.tar.gz": Cannot stat: No such file or directory                vÂ ÷Om7 7Þ'(tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Comment: Note that my command works perfectly when i execute it.
the errors occurs when i put it in a variable in shell script file and execute the script.

Comment: Then please post the code from your script. Do you use bash? Did you try a space between `prod_test.txt` and pipe?

Comment: Please also add the errors from your comment to the question by editing the latter.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
dy=`date +%a`
bk='/d01/backup'

#Transfer Command 
trans_oracle='tar cvzf -  prod_test.txt| ssh oracle@192.168.1.248 "cat >  prod_test4.tar.gz"'
#Delete Command
del_oracle='rm -f '$bk'/'$dy'_apps_indus_prod.tar.gz'


echo '****** Start Time ******' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
date >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
printf '\n' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'

#Transfer Backup
$trans_oracle
#Delete Backup
#$del_oracle

echo '******  End Time  ******' >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'
date >> $bk'/'$dy'_transfer_apps_bk_net.log'

Comment: @Farrukh We can't make much out of your code if you don't put it in the text of the question and format it properly. Please press the `edit` link above to edit the question.

Comment: @daniel not every version of `tar` defaults to _stdout_. It's better to be explicit and keep the `-f -` unless you can be absolutely sure if the default setting.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the remark. I didn't know.

Comment: @Farrukh What happens if you do not write the tar call into a variable but execute it directly in the script? Do you get the same error? (Also, as Rakesh noted in his answer, you should use `eval "$trans_oracle"`. But first just execute the command without the variable)

Answer (score 1):

To show the issue you are getting a small testcase will suffice:

Individually this runs fine:

```
ls; pwd
```

then we do this

```
cmd='ls ; pwd'
```

Now `$cmd` will give the error the files named ';' and 'pwd' are missing.

This is where precisely the "eval" command comes in when you want to give the shell another go:

```
eval "$cmd"
```

runs successfully as if you had given it at the command line.

So instead of $trans_oracle give it as: `eval "$trans_oracle"`

Comment: I have done this, actually the problem now is that it is showing errors
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
prod_test.txt
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Comment: but even then it is creating the tar file on my target server

Comment: This error indicates you are not using the -f option in tar. Give: tar cvzf - prod_test.txt | ....

Comment: finally this commnad works
tar -cz prod_test.txt | ssh oracle@192.168.1.248 "cat > /d01/prod_bk_net/PROD_TEST.tar.gz"'



but now i want to replace prod_text.txt with a directory